# Hamel basis and orthonormal basis for Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

My **question**:

> why don't we get a Hamel basis (a maximal linearly independent set)  instead of a maximal orthonormal set for a Hilbert space. In what dimension can we use a Hamel basis and in which we can't?

Comment: Hamel bases exist in any dimensions, assuming the Axiom of Choice. The problem is that Hamel need not be **orthonormal** in the infinite dimensional case, which is why we rather work with Hilbert bases, which always *are*. The tradeoff is that we must work with approximations instead of actual equalities, but the orthonormality of the Hilbert bases makes the tradeoff worthwhile most of the time.

Comment: In fact, Hamel bases _can't_ be orthonormal in the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: @Robert: I believe you...but maybe the proof of your above comment would make for a nice answer?

Comment: A Hamel basis of an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space cannot be orthonormal, but some Hamel bases of some infinite-dimensional inner product spaces (that are not complete) are orthonormal.  The space of trigonometric polynomials is an example.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Thank you; of course. Somehow I was thinking "Direct sum of copies of $F$", but although that's an infinite dimensional inner product space, it's not a Hilbert space. Silly me.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark:  If a Hilbert space $\cal H$ has an orthonormal Hamel basis $B$, then any member of $\cal H$, being a linear combination of finitely many members of $B$, is orthogonal to all the other members of $B$.  So take the sum of a convergent series involving a countable subset of $B$, say $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{b_j}{j^2}$, and you have a contradiction.

Comment: A related question: [An orthonormal set cannot be a basis in an infinite dimension vector space?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13641/an-orthonormal-set-cannot-be-a-basis-in-an-infinite-dimension-vector-space)

Comment: These are different concepts: Linear Basis: $v=\alpha_1b_1+\ldots\alpha_n b_n$ Approximate Linear Basis: $v\approx\lambda_1e_1+\ldots+\lambda_n e_n$

Answer (score 1):

We know the existence of a dense countable orthonormal set
i.e. $\fbox{1}\langle x,e_i\rangle \,$ for $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}$
$\, \Rightarrow x=0.\,$
Since a Hamel basis on a Hilbert  space is uncountable we can extend 
the linearly independent set $ \{ e_i\ | \forall i \in \mathbb{N} \}\,$ to a Hamel
basis in a non trivial way. So $\fbox{1} \,$ yields a contradiction.

Comment: I can't see why there is a contradiction. Could you clarify what is this argument supposed to show?