# Discontinuous linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I'm trying to find a discontinuous linear functional into $\mathbb{R}$ as a prep question for a test. I know that I need an infinite-dimensional Vector Space. Since $\ell_2$ is infinite-dimensional, there must exist a linear functional from $\ell_2$ into $\mathbb{R}$. However, I'm having trouble actually coming up with it.

I believe I'm supposed to find an unbounded function (although I'm not sure why an unbounded function is necessarily not continuous; some light in that regard would be appreciated too), so I thought of using the vectors $e^i$, which have all entries equal to zero, except for the $i$-th one. Then, you can define $f(e^i)=i$.  That'd be unbounded, but I'm not sure if it'd be linear, and even if it is, I'm not sure how to define it for all the other vectors in $\ell_2$.

A friend mentioned that at some point the question of whether the set $E=\{e^i:i\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is a basis would come up, but I'm not sure what a basis has to do with continuity of $f$.

I'm just learning this topic for the first time, so bear with me please.

The space of sequences that are eventually zero (suggested by a few people) turned out to be exactly what I needed.  It also helped to cement the notions of Hamel basis, not continuous, etc.

Comment: +1. Did you try other infinite-dimensional spaces? E.g., your idea of $f(e^i) = i$ will work automatically if you take the space of sequences with finitely many nonzero elements.

Comment: A linear map between two normed vector spaces is continuous if and only if it's bounded (in the operator norm). This is a well know result and the proof can be found in every book about functional analysis.

Comment: @Srivatsan thanks a lot.  I really like this idea of space of sequences with finitely many nonzero elements. I'll look into it and post back here what I find.

Comment: You can try to find an unbounded linear functional on a subspace and extend it using Hahn-Banach theorem. \\
If you are familiar with the notion of [Hamel basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamel_basis), it can also be used to prove the existence of unbounded functional on infinite dimensional normed spaces. See e.g. [Example 4.2](http://books.google.com/books?id=prfuUT0Sw-AC&pg=PA126) in  Heil: A basis theory primer. In fact, Srivatsan's comment above is a special case of this, since $\{e^i; i\in\mathbb N\}$ is a Hamel basis of the space of sequences that are eventually zero.

Comment: A similar question was also posted at MO: [Unbounded linear operator defined on $l^2$](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31163/unbounded-linear-operator-defined-on-l2/)

Comment: Relevant Wikipedia article: [Discontinuous linear map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuous_linear_map)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Zobr}[3]{#1:#2\to#3}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$ A different approach to show existence of unbounded functionals is using the notion of [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamel_basis).

*Definition:* Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$. We say that $B$ is a *Hamel basis*
in $V$ if $B$ is linearly independent and every vector $v\in V$
can be obtained as a linear combination of vectors from $B$. (By linearly independent we mean that if a finite linear combinations of elements of $B$ is zero, then all coefficients must be zero.)

This is equivalent to the condition that every $x\in V$ can be written in precisely one way as
$$\sum_{i\in F} c_i x_i$$
where $F$ si finite, $c_i\in K$ and $x_i\in B$ for each $i\in F$.

This is probably better known in the finite-dimensional case, but many properties of bases remain true in the infinite-dimensional case as well:

- Every vector space has a Hamel basis. In fact, every linearly independent set is contained in a Hamel basis.
- Any two Hamel bases of the same space have the same cardinality.
- Choosing images of basis vector uniquely determines a linear function, i.e.,
  if $B$ is a basis of $V$ then for any vector space $W$ and any map $\Zobr gBW$ there exists exactly one linear map $\Zobr fVW$ such that $f|_B=g$.

---

**Claim:** If $X$ is an infinite-dimensional linear normed space, then there exist non-continuous linear function $\Zobr fX{\R}$.

See also [Example 4.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=prfuUT0Sw-AC&pg=PA126) in Heil: A basis theory primer.

*Proof.* Choose an infinite linearly independent set $\{x_n; n\in\mathbb N\}$ such that $\|x_n\|=1$. (An infinite linearly independent set exists, since $X$ is infinite-dimensional. Normalizing the vectors does not influence the linear independence.) There is a Hamel basis $B$ containing this set.

Then there is a linear function $\Zobr fX{\R}$ such that $f(x_n)=n$ and $f(b)=0$ for $b\in B\setminus\{x_n; n\in\mathbb N\}$. This function is obviously unbounded. $\square$

In fact, Srivatsan's comment above is a special case of this result, since $\{e^i; i\in\mathbb N\}$ is a
Hamel basis of the space $c_{00}$ of sequences that are eventually zero.

---

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87420/8297) is very similar to this one.

The above was taken from [these notes](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/texty/rozne/pozn/tm/hamel.pdf) of mine. Several more results and references can be found there. I have also mentioned some basic facts about Hamel basis in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88058/8297) at this site.

You can also find much more information about Hamel bases at other posts at this site:
["Hamel basis"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Hamel+basis%22), [hamel basis site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=hamel+basis+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Why is $f$ linear. I am making a mistake but I don't see it. $f(e_i+e_j)\neq f(e_i)+f(e_j)$, since $e_i+e_j$ is not in $B$, $f(e_i+e_j)$=0.

Comment: If we define values of a map on basic elements, then there is unique linear extension. (See the paragraph starting: *Choosing images of basis vector uniquely determines...*) It works similarly in finite-dimensional case.

Comment: Now, I see @Martin. By which theorem is this implied?

Comment: I have tried to give some explanation [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/10940/hamel-basis), in order to avoid long discussion in comments here.

Answer (score 29):

You won't find an explicit example of a discontinuous linear functional defined everywhere on a Banach space: these require the Axiom of Choice.  However, you can find a discontinuous linear functional on a normed linear space.  A typical scenario would be that you have Banach space $X$ (whose norm I'll denote $\|.\|_X$) which is a dense linear subspace of Banach space $Y$ (under a different norm $\|.\|_Y$, where $\|x\|_X \ge \|x\|_Y$ for all $x \in X$), and a linear functional $\phi$ on $X$ 
which is continuous for the norm $\|.\|_X$ but not for the norm $\|.\|_Y$.  Thus if you take $X$ with the norm $\|.\|_Y$, you have a normed linear space with a discontinuous linear functional $\phi$.  For example, take $X = \ell_2$, $Y = \ell_\infty$, and $\phi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i/i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Two things:

1) What if we do use AC? Is it true then that such a discontinuous linear functional always exists? 
2) Is the last sum supposed to be indexed by $i$ instead of $j$?

Comment: 1) Yes, in any infinite-dimensional vector space, if $e_1, e_2, \ldots$ is a linearly independent sequence you can define $\phi(e_j)$ arbitrarily and use Axiom of Choice to extend this to a linear functional on the whole space.  2) Yes, thanks for correcting this typo.

Comment: When you say X is a subspace of Y should you not specify with respect to which norm X is a subspace, especially given that you take the two spaces with different norms?

Comment: Being a subspace has nothing to do with norms: $X$ is a linear subspace of $Y$ if it is a subset that is closed under addition and under multiplication by scalars.

Answer (score 22):

As Robert Israel already mentioned, you cannot write down an explicit (free of the axiom of choice) unbounded linear functional on a Banach space.  But it's generally not hard for incomplete normed spaces.  Nobody has mentioned my favorite example: the functional $\ell: C^1[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\ell(f) = f'(0)$.

Comment: Where $C^1[-1,1]$ has the *uniform* norm.  (If it has the $C^1$ norm, then this functional is continuous.)

Comment: Is the uniform norm the same as the supremum norm?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by $C^1 [-1,1]$?

Comment: @gen Yes, the uniform norm is the sup-norm and $C^1$ is the set of differentiable functions with continuous derivatives.