# Example of an unbounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Can somebody give me an easy example of a linear operator which maps $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (but not boundedly) but does *not* admit a bounded extension from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (or any other $L^p$, $1<p<\infty$) ?

Comment: You've done a search on google?

Comment: What about a differentiation operator, say w.r.t. one coordinate?

Comment: And how should I extend it to L^1 and L^inf?

Comment: @Berci Could you precise what you have in mind? I understand you suggest $f\mapsto f'$ possibly extended by density. But this does not even send the bounded differentiable functions to $L^\infty$ ($x^2\sin (1/x^2)$).

Comment: @Anonymous999 You can extend linear operators using some (non-explicit) algebraic basis of $L^1$ or $L^\infty$. Follow the proof of the Hahn-Banach theorem, but drop the majorizing sublinear functional from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no explicit (easy or otherwise) examples of unbounded linear operators (or functionals) defined on a Banach space. Their very existence depends on the axiom of choice. See [Discontinuous linear functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99206/79365).

Comment: That's only if you require your operator to be defined everywhere. Otherwise it is very easy, like differentiation on $C^1[0,1]$ as a dense subspace of $C[0,1]$. In ththe case of the question above, it is clearly **not** asking for an everywhere-defined operator.

Comment: @MartinArgerami *Clearly*? The question says "maps $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$..", no mention of a dense subspace. When suggested a densely defined operator (differentiation) OP responded with "And how should I extend it to $L^1$ and $L^\infty$?"

Comment: Well, I have to admit that not "clearly". Since none of the spaces the OP mentions are included in each other, I'm not sure what he is looking for.