# If the quotient of a subspace of a banach space is finite, is it a closed subspace?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given a Banach space B，V is a subspace of B，if B/V is finite dimension，then is it enough to show that B is closed?

Thanks!

Comment: See [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/30868/1409) in MathOverflow

Comment: Thanks for your comment and great reference. I need to think for a while.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and great reference. I am sorry that the following question may be unclear. Is there concrete construction that the kernel can be described concretely?

Comment: Find any non-zero linear functional on an infinite dimensional Banach space which is not continuous. Doing that explicitly needs recourse to the axiom of choice. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31163/unbounded-linear-operator-defined-on-l2/