# Give an example of a linear mapping from a normed space into a normed space which is not continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Give an example of a linear mapping from a normed space into a normed space which is not continuous.

I can't think of anything.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You can search for "not continuous linear operator" in this site and you will surely find one, but don't give up, try to find one on your own!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discontinuous linear functional](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: try checking that $P([0,1]) \ni p \mapsto p' \in P([0,1])$ is not bounded in the unit sphere. Here $P([0, 1])$ is the space of polynomials in $[0,1]$, with the sup norm.