# Convex and dense subset in infinite-dimensional normed vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional normed vector space. How to construct proper convex subset $A$ of $X$, s. th. $A$ is dense in $X$ ?

If $X$ is an unitary vector space then it is obvious, but how to do it in more general case ?

Comment: Take the kernel of a [discontinuous linear functional](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional).

Comment: Thanks ! It actually was obvious. :)

Comment: I wonder if it can be done without choice.