# $f \in \mathcal l^{\infty}{'} $ ; $f(x)\ge 0$ whenever $x \in \mathcal l^{\infty} $ is a sequence of non-negative terms ; is $f$ bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $f:\mathcal l^{\infty} \to \mathbb R$ be a linear functional such that $f(x)\ge 0$ whenever $x \in \mathcal l^{\infty} $ is a sequence with non-negative terms ; then is $f$ continuous ?

Comment: Do you, by $l^\infty$, mean the space of bounded sequences?

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä : Yes , indeed the space of bounded sequences

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/99242/66856