# linear map on Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Can we say that every linear map on Banach space $X$, for example $ f : X ‎‎‎‎\longrightarrow  ‎\mathbb{C}‎‎ $ must be continuous and bounded?

if the answer is negative, please give me an example.

Comment: Unbounded linear functionals can be constructed as open ball suggests, there is a more detailed discussion here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional

Answer (score 5):

If $X$ is infinite dimensional, no. In fact you can construct one given any such $X$. Let $\{e_a: a\in I \}$ be a basis of $X$ where $\|e_a\| = 1$ for all $a$. There exists a countable subset (now I'll be a little bit sloppy) $\{e_n :n\in \Bbb N\}$. Now define $L: X \to \Bbb C$ to be the linear function such that $Le_a = 0$ if $a\in I\setminus \Bbb N$ and $Le_n = n$ for $n\in \Bbb N$. Then $L$ is not bounded.

Comment: @IvoTerek thanks! I believe that sloppiness is a good thing when the details are just noise.