# Is there an example of a linear map between Banach Spaces that is not closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is there a simple example of a linear map $T: X \to Y$ between Banach spaces that is not closed, i.e. if $x_n \to 0$ in $X$ and $T(x_n) \to y$ in $Y$, then $y=0$? I know the Closed Graph Theorem says that if $T: X \to Y$ is a linear map between Banach spaces, then
\begin{align*}
T \text{ is bounded } \iff T \text{ is closed } \iff \text{gr}(T) \text { is a closed subspace of } X \oplus Y.
\end{align*}
So I would have to find an unbounded linear map between Banach spaces, correct? What exactly would that be?

Comment: Have a look at the asnwers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567528/any-examples-of-unbounded-linear-operators-between-ell-infty-and-ell-inft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can construct an unbounded linear functional easily. Pick your favorite basis $e_n$ with $\lVert e_n \rVert = 1$ of $X$ (which can be done with the axiom of  choice) and define $f$ as
$$f(x)=\sum_n n x_n,\,\,\,\,\text{where }\,\,\,\,x=\sum_n x_n e_n.$$
Note that this is well-defined, as $x_n$ is non-zero for finitely many $n$ for every $x$. Then pick
$$y_n = \frac{e_n}{\sqrt{n}},$$ which clearly goes to $0$, but $f(y_n)=\sqrt{n} \to +\infty$.

Comment: What exactly would $X$ and $Y$ be? Are there any concrete Banach spaces that this works for?

Comment: @MATH-LORD Pick your favorite Banach space $X$ over the field $\mathbb{F}$ and $Y=\mathbb{F}$. Note that you can't construct this function "exactly", but you can prove that it exists.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help!