# Example of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space that is not an RKHS

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I have been studying Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces (RKHS). The definition I am using is as follows: An RKHS is a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ of real-valued functions on a set $X$ such that for all $x \in X$, the evaluation functional $E_x : \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $E_x(f) = f(x)$ is continuous. (Recall that continuity in this context means $\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1}|f(x)| < \infty$ for all $x$.)

As one of the first steps in my study I want to see some positive and negative examples of these spaces. So I want to find a non-trivial (meaning infinite dimensional) space of functions which is a Hilbert space but not an RKHS, meaning the evaluation functionals are not continuous.

The problem is that in all the references I find, the only example they give is the space of functions $L_{2}$. However, this example is trivial since $L_2$ fails for the simple reason that it is not a space of functions, rather it contains equivalence classes of functions.

Can someone please help me find an infinite dimensional Hilbert space of functions that is not an RKHS?

Comment: Why not just consider $\mathcal{L}_2$, i.e. $L_2$ before taking equivalence classes? That is a hilbert space of functions.

Comment: @user27182 See both answers below. The problem is that $\mathcal{L}_2$ is not a space of functions; rather, elements of that space are equivalence classes of functions.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_2$ is a space of functions (it's the space of all square integrable functions, which you turn it into $L_2$ by considering equivalence classes), the problem with my earlier comment is that it is not an inner product space (so not a Hilbert space).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no explicit examples of this kind. Indeed, if one could show you such a space $\mathcal H$, then point evaluation $f\mapsto f(x_0)$  would give an explicit example of a discontinuous linear functional on a Hilbert space. And there can be no explicit examples of this kind, because **it's consistent with [ZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) that they do not exist**. Only with the Axiom of Choice can one give a (non-constructive) proof of their existence. This is discussed in many places, such as

- [Discontinuous linear functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional)
- [Unbounded linear operator defined on $l^2$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/31163)

So, any time someone gives you a concrete Hilbert space of functions, you can be sure that it's either RKHS, or is not really a space of functions.

Comment: That's very interesting. So if I understand correctly, there can not be "constructive" example of a Hilbert space of functions and point $x_0$, such that the evaluation functional at that point is discontinuous?