# Is a convex function on an infinite dimensional cube bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Suppose $f : [0, 1]^\alpha \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex. Does it follow that $f$ has a lower bound?

I've shown that this holds for finite $α$. My question is whether it also holds for infinite $α$.

In the finite case, I can prove it by induction. First, we show this for an interval $[0, 1]$. (For convex $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, for $x ≥ \frac{1}{2}$ we have $f(x) ≥ 2f(\frac{1}{2}) - f(0)$, and a similar bound holds for $x ≤ \frac{1}{2}$.)

Next, suppose that $f : [0, 1]^{n + 1} \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex. Then for each $x ∈ [0, 1]$, let $f_x$ be the function that takes $y ∈ [0, 1]^n$ to $f(x, y_1, …, y_n)$. Then each function $f_x$ is convex, and thus by the inductive hypothesis it is bounded. Let $b(x)$ be the greatest lower bound of $f_x$. Then $b : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is also convex. (For any $ε > 0$, there are $y$ and $y'$ such that $f_x(y) < b(x) + \frac{ε}{2}$ and $f_{x'}(y') < b(x') + \frac{ε}{2}$. So 
\begin{align}
b(λx + (1-λ)x') 
& ≤ f(λx + (1-λ)x', y) \\
& ≤ λf(x, y) + (1 - λ)f(x', y') \\
& < λb(x) + (1 - λ)b(x') + ε
\end{align}
So $b(λx + (1-λ)x') ≤ λb(x) + (1 - λ)b(x')$.)
So by the first part, $b$ also has a lower bound, and this must be a lower bound for $f$.

It seems like a similar argument using transfinite induction might work in general, but I don't know how the limit step would go.

Comment: Have you tried something like an $f$ such that $f(x) = 0$ is $0$ if $x_i$ is non-zero for infinitely many $i$ and is $\sum_i x_i$ otherwise?

Comment: Nope, I didn't think of that. Looks like that works as a counterexample (if we just change the sign).

Comment: Oh, wait, I was mixed up. If we keep the sign the same, we still have a lower bound. If we switch the sign, though, this is no longer convex, but rather concave. Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not seeing how to get a counterexample out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it may not be bounded below. Consider $K=[0,1]^\alpha$ as a subset of the Banach space $\ell^\infty(\alpha)$. $K$ is a neighbourhood of the point $u=\left(\frac12,\frac12,\cdots\right)$. If $\alpha\ge\aleph_0$, then there is a discontinuous linear functional $\phi:\ell^\infty(\alpha)\to \Bbb R$. Discontinuous functionals are unbounded (in both directions) on every open sets, therefore $f(x)=\phi(x-u)$ is a convex function $K\to\Bbb R$ without lower bounds.

Comment: Cool, very helpful. Now that I know what terms to search for, it looks like [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional) is relevant. The answer provides a more explicit construction of such a function. Let $α = ω$. We can extend the set of vectors $e_n$ to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^ω$. Then there is a unique linear function $f : \mathbb{R}^ω \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(e_n) = n$, and $f(v) = 0$ for the other basis vectors $v$ besides the vectors $e_n$. It's clear that $f$ is unbounded.