# Is the set $G=\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in \ell_2: \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}=0\}$ closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I am very confused whether or not the set

> $G=\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \in \ell_2: \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}=0\}$

is  closed in $\ell_2$. Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: The specification of $G$ is incomplete, are you missing an order of some sort?

Comment: To clarify copper.hat's issue, you the criterion for $x \in G$, is incomplete, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is not a logical statement.

Comment: That's all I was given, thus I am very confused

Comment: I fixed it thanks!

Comment: How is that sequence a counterexample?

Comment: Also why is your title about compactness but your question about closedness? These are not the same.

Comment: Compactness and Closed is the same, I am fixing it just in case

Comment: Compactness and closedness are ***not*** the same in general. In metric spaces this is true iff the space is compact, which your space is not.

Comment: $l_2$ is already a metric space from what have learned

Comment: I don't think that the set $G$ is well defined. I believe (based on a reading of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99213/27978) that $\sum_k {x_k \over \sqrt{k}}$ is not defined for all of $l_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-1,0,\dots),  (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},0,-1,0,\dots), \ldots $ belong to $G$. Moreover, note that $G\neq\ell_2$.

Let us assume that $G$ is closed. Since $G\neq\ell_2$, there is a non-null vector $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ orthogonal to $G$.
Therefore $(x_n)$ is orthogonal to each sequence above.

Thus, $\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{2}}-x_2=0$, $\ \frac{x_1}{\sqrt{3}}-x_3=0$, $\ \ldots.\ $  So $x_n=\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Note that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=\left(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ belongs to $\ell_2$ if only if $x_1=0$. Absurd!

Comment: I actually figured out something similar, but yours is better