# Must a linear operator that vanishes on the basis vectors vanish everywhere?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis $e_1,e_2,\dots$. Consider a linear functional $L: H\to \mathbb{R}$, which may be bounded or not, that obeys $L(e_i)=0$ for all $e_i$. Does that imply that $L(x)=0$ for all $x\in H$?

Comment: No. It only implies it for continuous, equivalently bounded, linear functionals. However, everywhere defined [unbounded linear functionals](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99242/152568) are rather exotic objects that can only be constructed using the axiom of choice via the so-called Hamel basis.

Comment: Slightly more explicitly, consider the quotient of $H$ by the (non-closed) subspace spanned by the $e_i$. Since $H$ is uncountable-dimensional and the subspace is countable-dimensional this quotient is also uncountable-dimensional, and in particular nonzero. So the axiom of choice can be used to construct a nonzero linear functional on it, which pulls back to an unbounded nonzero linear functional on $H$ vanishing on the $e_i$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan and @ Conifold: these comments should be answers imo.

Comment: I'm happy to accept some combination of these comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete $\{ e_n \}$ to a Hamel basis $\{ f_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ for $H$ where $f_{\alpha_n} = e_{n}$. Then define a linear functional $\Phi$ on $\{ f_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ in such a way that $\Phi(f_{\alpha_n})=0$ but so that $\Phi \ne 0$. This is possible because $\{ e_n \}$ cannot be a Hamel basis.