# Projection Operator Question in Brezis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Here I attach the theorem and comment that I am confused about:
[image]

[image]

I am confused about the comment right below the definition. From what I learned in topology, all projection maps are continuous. If this is true, why do we need Theorem 2.10 to obtain this result?

Comment: The projection mapping $P:X\to X$, by definition satisfies $P\circ P=P.$ The continuity does not follows automatically. For example, concerning Theorem 2.10, if $G+L$ is not closed, then the conclusion does not hold and the projection operators described in Definition are not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[One can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional) that on every Banach space $X$, there exists a discontinuous linear functional $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$. Let $x\in X$ be such that $f(x)=1$. Define $P:X\to X$ by $Py = f(y)x$. It is not difficult to show that $P$ is linear and $P^2=P$. Since $f$ is discontinuous, so is $P$.